# Converting single point layer to buffered raster using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, buffer, rasterization

I'm trying to use the proximity tool to create a distance raster from a single vector point. I found here: [Calculating distance to points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/calculating-distance-to-points-in-qgis) and [[d-3] Create Proximity Raster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpuyy7U0hxg). However, I couldn't go past the first step which is rasterizing the vector point layer.

I couldn't figure out how to rasterize the single point and extend the raster to a specified distance, like a buffer, and set all the other values to nan or zero. I've tried the different rasterizing tools available in QGIS but I couldn't find anything that works.

Comment: GDAL rasterize allows you to use an existing output raster, there's a bit of a hack https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69600/how-to-create-a-raster-from-scratch to create an empty raster. I think the problem you're having is that the output extent can't be set as you've only got 1 point... you could also try buffering the point, exporting the buffer to raster and then use gdal_calc to create an empty matching raster https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220753/how-do-i-create-blank-geotiff-with-same-spatial-properties-as-existing-geotiff

Comment: Hi Michael, yes you were right. I had trouble converting the single point to a raster. I've also thought of and tried buffering the point and then converting to raster. And I've used raster calc to empty all the values. What I could not figure out is how to bring back the value at the original point location?

Comment: GDAL_Rasterize with a target of your freshly emptied raster, as the raster already exists it will be updated with your current point location. Earlier versions of this tool *required* an existing raster, not being able to create a new raster, that has been fixed but if you supply an existing raster as an output it operates as it did before keeping the integrity of your existing raster.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the response. I've managed to do the gdal_rasterize function which overwrites a target raster layer when I used QGIS 2.18. But I was initially using version 3.2 for my project, and I was wondering if the same output could be achieved. According to the gdal_rasterize description here: https://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html, it will only overwrite when some options are not used in the call. But I couldn't figure out how to achieve this from playing around with the parameters, since I could no longer edit the gdal call directly in QGIS 3.2

Comment: That's worth asking as a new question. AFAIK nothing has changed with GDAL_Rasterize but if the QGIS 3.2 interface will no longer let you edit the commandline that is a significant fault; there may be some 'trick' to editing the command line but I haven't used 3.2 enough to know.